# Rsync filter and ignore some directories

Tags: rsync, filter

I'd like to rsync a directory that contains a Python 3 app on my server.

The directory has files I'm interested in: the files that end with .py

And there are the files I'd like to be ignored (these are the files that are inside a `__pycache__` directory). (note: there could be `__pycache__` directories in any subdirectory of my project). I'd like these `__pycache__` directories to be ignored, wherever they appear).

I thought there should be an easy way to do this but couldn't find it. The --filter option appears to be undocumented and the --exclude option doesn't work as described in the rsync help.

Comment: Look at the `--exclude-from` option.

Comment: I don't know in advance where nor how many the `__pycache__` directories are going to be.

Comment: What have you already tried with --exclude that didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

`rsync -a --exclude "__pycache__/" source/ destination/`

You may also want to pass `--delete-excluded` to remove `__pycache__` files that have been copied (of course it removes all other excluded files from the destination too too).

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -a --exclude '__pycache__' source/ destination/
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The `__pycache__` directory is still sent.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync -av --exclude=*__pycache__ source/ destination/`

Comment: It yould be nice to have the command explained, especially `--exclude` so that OP could learn from this, not just see the solution itself (which is IMHO completely correct).

Comment: i just posted a fixed syntax (answers above didn't work for me)